# Django 1.9. не могу сделать виджет как в оригинале для выбора группы

Tags: django

Django 1.9. 
Сделал свою модель пользователя.
Не получается сделать виджет для выбор группы или разрешений для пользователя.

## Так выглядит мой виджет пользователя

[image: Так выглядит мой виджет пользователя]

## Так выглядит оригинальный виджет

[image: Так выглядит оригинальный виджет]
    #
    # Код =========admin.py===========
    #

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from accounts.models import Organization, AccountsUser,  AccountsUserAppointment, AccountsUserUnit

@admin.register(AccountsUser)

class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'last_name',
                    'first_name', 'hide',
                    'appointment', 'unit',
                    'is_staff', 'is_active',
                    'date_joined', 'last_login',)

exclude = ('password', )

fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('email', 'hide', 'avatar')}),
    (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('last_name', 'first_name',
                        'middle_name', 'birthday', 'organization', 'unit',
                        'appointment', 'hide_contacts', 'phone_1', 'phone_2', 'phone_3', )}),
    (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
    (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
)

admin.site.register(Organization)
admin.site.register(AccountsUserAppointment)
admin.site.register(AccountsUserUnit)
```

Как сделать виджет так как в оригинальной админки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение.
Добавляем в переопределенную модель в файле admin.py

```
filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
```

И все ок.=)